# Can't make SPDY work on Apache 2.2.22 (Ubuntu 12.04 server)

Tags: ssl, http, https, ubuntu-12.04, spdy

I'm trying to enable this apache module. I did everything this documentation from Google says: https:// developers.google.com/speed/spdy/mod_spdy/

However, if I use "SPDY indicator" chrome extension to check if it's working it shows that it DOESN'T.

Another tools I used to check if it works is https://spdycheck.org/ 
The results are strange. If I check "www.example.com" it says it's supporting SPDY. However, if I check "example.com", it says it doesn't.

Finally, https://www.h2check.org/ says it doesn't support HTTP/2 when I check "www.example.com", but if I insert my IP Address it says it DOES support it.

I'm lost, because it seems like it's not working but some of this tools say it is ( under different scenarios ).

Why am I getting different results from different tests, and how can I get SPDY working properly?

Comment: did you restart apache?

Comment: several times, and modified config files several times as well

Comment: Getting spdy to work properly on apache is a huge PITA...I gave up after about a day.  Here's hoping someone posts a good answer to this!